# Controlling delegate method call in viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, controller

I have 3 controllers lined up as in say my 3 controllers are ControllerA, ControllerB and ControllerC.

```
 - ControllerA navigates to ControllerB.
 - ControllerB can navigate to ControllerA (using Back Button) and can navigate to ControllerC.
 - ControllerC can navigate to ControllerB.
```

I have a protocol and delegate in ControllerB and its implementation is in ControllerA.

***ControllerB.h***

```
@protocol ControllerBDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)someMethod;
@end
```

***ControllerB.m***

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.delegate someMethod];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ControllerC *controllerC = [[ControllerC alloc] init];
   [controllerC navigateToView];
}
```

***ControllerA.h***

```
@interface ControllerB : UITableViewController <ControllerADelegate>
@end
```

***ControllerA.m***

```
- (void)someMethod
{
  // Some method and its implementation logic.
}
```

***Question:***
When I click on Back button on ControllerB, viewWillDisappear gets called and it executes the logic inside 'someMethod()' defined in ControllerA which is as required. But when I click on a cell to navigate to ControllerC, since the ControllerB is disappearing, this time  as well it calls viewWillDisappear and executes the logic inside 'someMethod()' defined in ControllerA and after that it navigates to ControllerC.

Is there a way I can avoid the execution or the viewWillDisappear in ControllerB to avoid making a call to someMethod() when it navigates to ControllerC. In short, I don't want ControllerB to call and execute someMethod() when I am navigating to ControllerC.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance variable called `BOOL isNavigating`

set `isNavigating = YES;` on the `- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Your `viewWillDisappear` method should be something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (!isNavigating) {
        [self.delegate someMethod];
    }
}
```

Remember to set `isNavigating = NO;` on the `viewWillAppear` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid the call to viewWillDisappear - this is part of the standard view lifecycle.  You can replace the standard back button in ControllerB with your own and establish an event handler for it.  This event handler can fire the delegate method and pop the view.

In your viewDidLoad method -

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle @"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Then add your action method -

```
- (void)goBack:(id)sender
{
   if (self.delegate != nil)
   {
     [self.delegate someMethod];
   }

   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

The other approach is to use a storyboard and segues.  You can then perform the appropriate processing in `prepareForSegue`